# Run Asp.net Application as Console Application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to run an ASP.NET C# app as console application from Visual Studio, but I haven't been able to find how. I want to test some part of my application which doesn't depend on a web server and reduce launch time by that way. Any idea about how to do this?

Comment: You may be interested in "self hosting asp.net app without iis"

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET and console application are two very different types of applications. You can't run one as other.

However, there are a few things you can do to save yourself some grief. Refactor your application. Add a new project of type `Class Library` to your solution. Then move the common part of the application (that doesn't depend on web server) into a class file in that class library project. Then reference this class library in asp.net application.

This class library can now be used in any type of .NET project. For example, in this case just create a new console application and reference this class library to test.

Hope this helps.